# jQuery combine .ready and .resize

Tags: jquery, resize, ready

Some (well, nearly all) of my code that is in my jQuery .ready function also applies when the window is resized, as it's layout work. However, since it's the same code, how could I "combine" the two functions, so that my code doesn't repeat itself (and be a mess to maintain)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).on('resize',myfunction);

function myfunction() {
    // do whatever
}
```

Another technique is to `.trigger()` one event inside the other:

```
$(window).on('resize',function() {
    // do whatever
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

If you put your code at the bottom of the page to avoid needing `$(document).ready`, it gets even simpler:

```
$(window).on('resize',function() {
    // do whatever
}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: And even simpler: $(window).resize(function() { //do whatever }).resize();

Comment: @Kudla69 I always prefer writing `.trigger('thing')` instead of just `.thing()` in jQuery, just because I find it more clear as a reader.

Comment: you freaken genius

Comment: Is there a way to fire off multiple functions within `$(document).ready(myfunction);`?

Comment: @stinkysGTI Yes, create an anonymous function that calls them one by one.

Comment: @Blazemonger that's exactly what I ended up doing, thank you :)

Answer (score 13):

One more better option

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(e){
  function abc() {
    // code here
  }
});
```

Comment: `load` works differently from `ready` otherwise this would work.

Comment: Just for clarification on UXCODA's comment: `load` and `resize` are callback jQuery wrappers  for the `window` DOM object's `onload` and `onresize` callbacks (respectively). `ready` is a jQuery callback that tracks the DOMContentLoaded event. `ready` would allow for manipulation as soon as the DOM is ready, while `window.onload` is much later in the lifecycle. If anything is put in this handler that is time-intensive, it will cause the DOM to flicker. https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 8):

Something like this??

```
function mySetupFunction() {
    // stuff here.
}

$(document).ready(mySetupFunction);
$(window).resize(mySetupFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code might be helpful to do things after `resize is ready`.

```
var resizeTimer;

$(window).on('resize', function(e) {

  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {

    // Run code here after resizing has done
            
  }, 250);

});
```

Here is the issue with the following that the code is running while resize is under going.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
  // Run code here while resizing is under going
});
```